# How can I Resize & Enlarge an Image (like sprite icons) via CSS 3?

Tags: resize, css, size, background-image

Dear folks.
Imagine a sprite image called `icons.png` assigned to css class `.icons` with various 10x10px graphs. Now you want another class which scales up the sprite graphics exactly twice 200% (making them 20x20 pixels on the screen)

**How do I achieve this enlargement *purely* in CSS?**
Much appreciated!

```
.icons, .iconsbig{    /* WORKS FINE */
background-image:url(http://site.org/icons.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
vertical-align: middle;
display: block;
height:10px;
}

.iconsbig{    /* make this one twice as big as the original sprite */
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:20px;
background-size: 20px auto;
    image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor;
}
```

## update:

problems with the above code:

- It works in IE9, but not in FireFox, by most used browser doesnt know how to resize????
- in IE9, the enlargement is smudgy and not neithrest neighbour pixel perfect at all??

Comment: BTW, that second selector should have a `.` prepended :)

Comment: Thanks Alex. All seem work Perfect now in FireFox!!!!  except the crispness in IE9: its not the sharp,pixely result I wanted. All i get is smoothened, photoshop-ish enlargements... There is something wrong with the `-ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor`...

Comment: @Sam IE gains more support, but still finds a way to make life difficult :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t44) in pretty much everything except for < IE9...

```
.iconsbig {  
    -moz-background-size: 20px;
    background-size: 20px;
    image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor;
}
```

[W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size).

#### Update

[Looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ETBwx/) Firefox wants its vendor prefix (`-moz`) on the property.

Comment: +1 Thanks, which browsers does this suport? which ones not? ( you see, the problem is that the browser I care about, my clients don't use, helas :)

Comment: @Sam [Looks like](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t44) everything except for < IE9.

Comment: @Sam That's less than IE9, so IE6/7/8 :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css3 `background-size` property:

```
.iconsbig {
  background-image:url(http://site.org/icons.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```